# Re-ording the display order of tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sorting, adminer

This is purely for convenience.

New tables are added to the bottom of the list of tables when using Adminer (http://www.adminer.org/) - how can I make these tables appear at the top of the list?

These tables are my own and not part of the CMS I use, therefore I use them a lot and need to look at them a lot. With 170 tables this is annoying having to scroll through them all to get to mine.

How can I make Adminer or MySQL reorder these tables?

Comment: Request a feature from the author of Adminer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you use Adminer install [`AdminerTablesFilter` plugin](http://www.adminer.org/en/plugins/).
   It might be even handier than a fixed order.
2. Switch to some other tool which supports sorting filtering. (I use SequelPro a lot)
3. Learn to use mysql CLI. You have to type a lot when you work with SQL anyway. CLI supports auto-complete.
4. Request a feature from the author of Adminer
5. Add this feature to Adminer yourself through a plug-in or introduce `order by` clauses to selects from information_schema to sources.

Answer (score 1):

Adminer sorts tables by name. To change the order, you can implement the `tablesPrint()` method in [customization](http://www.adminer.org/en/extension/).